# how to remove only the desired row from the matrix and return the rest rows of a matrix using matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to get the output removing only a single row and returning rest rows using matlab.
For eg: Consider a matrix

```
A = [1  1  1; 2  2  2; 3  3  3; 4  4  4]
```

For case1, I need to have a separate matrix where first matrix is displaying the desired rows and other matrix displays the rest rows.

like `B=1` then output will be two matrix where first matrix will be

```
C = [1  1  1]
```

and another matrix will be

```
D = [2  2  2; 3  3  3; 4  4  4]
```

similarly in next case `B=2`

then

```
C = [2  2  2]
D = [1  1  1; 3  3  3; 4  4  4]
```

How to write a matlab program for such case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, given your definitions of `A` and `B`

```
C = A(B,:)
D = A(setdiff(1:size(A,1),B),:)
```

I expect you can easily wrap these up into a function.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
 A =

 1     1     1
 2     2     2
 3     3     3
 4     4     4

row=2;
A(row,:)=[]

A =

 1     1     1
 3     3     3
 4     4     4
```

To preserve the original matrix and to save the row, I would use something like the following function:

```
function [ A,out_row ] = removerow( A,row )
%row is the number of the row you want to remove, and 
%A is the matrix you want it removed from.
out_row=A(row,:);
A(row,:)=[];
end
```

Comment: But how to make a loop for choosing row one by one and displaying the rest matrix.

Comment: Note that this is a destructive operation, after executing `A(row,:) = []` `A` becomes a 3-row array.  This does not seem to satisfy the original requirements.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - Good point, I just figured that he would use it in something similar to the function I just edited in.

Answer (score 0):

You can Extract a row this way:

```
C = A(1,:)
C =

   1   1   1
```

You can Extract mulitple rows this way 2:4 expands to [ 2 3 4 ]

```
D = A(2:4,: )
D =

   2   2   2
   3   3   3
   4   4   4
```

and the second colon in 'A(1, :) expands to all available columns.

hope this helps